# Why need web.debug.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, transformation

When build and run in VS, VS won't do web.config transformation, IISExpress always reads and uses web.config. Web.config transformation only happens when deploy. 
Then why we need web.debug.config? We can add set all debug purpose properties in web.config directly, like `<compilation debug="true">`, then override those properties in web.release.config when do deployment. The whole process looks like it doesn't need web.debug.config at all.
Does anyone know why we need web.debug.config? Someone may say when we want to deploy debug build to web server, well, if that is the case it can also done by direct copy web.config to web server.

Answer (score 0):

these files are added by default based on your default build configurations (Release and Debug). Acutally you can freely delete this file assuming that every publish and deploy to environment different than dev should be in Release mode.